# Asserting individual Objects in List using AssertJ

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assertj

I am using AssertJ library to perform assertions in my test. In this case I want to test if every `Date` object in list is after other date.

So I can obviously do the following:

```
Date dateOne = new Date(someTimestamp);
Date dateTwo = new Date(otherTimestamp);

Assertions.assertThat(dateOne).isAfter(dateTwo);
```

No questions about it.

But what if I want to test every element of list to make sure that all of them are after given date.

```
Date dateOne = new Date(someTimestamp);
Date dateTwo = new Date(otherTimestamp);
Date dateThree = new Date(fooBarTimestamp);

List<Date> dates = Arrays.asList(dateOne, dateTwo);

//and here I want to make sure that all Dates in dates are after dateThree
```

I managed this by creating custom `org.assertj.core.api.Condition` and used this syntax:

```
Assertions.assertThat(dates).is(allAfterDate(dateThree));
```

but the comparator does look very neat and what most important, my SonarQube is complaining that this signature:

```
Condition<List<? extends Date>> allAfterDate(final Date dateToCompare) {...}
```

Is breaking [Generic wildcard types should not be used in return parameters](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1452) rule. I tend to believe in SonarQube if I am not sure that this is a rule that I can break this time. And I am not sure.

I like using `SoftAssertions` so the walkaround would be to use:

```
SoftAssertions assertions = new SoftAssertions();

dates.forEach( date -> {
    assertions.assertThat(date).isAfter(dateThree);
});

assertions.assertAll();
```

But I just cannot feel that this should be possible to use this cool AssertJ syntax that most devs like that much ;-)

Is there a way that I can do something similar to this?

```
Assertions.assertThat(dates).everySingleElement().isAfter(dateThree);
```

And if this is not possible what would be the best and cleanest way to do this?

(And I know I can supress sonar with `//NOSONAR`, I just don't want to)

---

Comment: So what is your question? What is the best way? How to fix your sonarqube warning regarding the generics?

Comment: Sorry, edited so the question is more clear. Can I use something similar to `Assertions.assertThat(dates).everySingleElement().isAfter(dateThree);` or if not what is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`allSatisfy`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html):

```
assertThat(dates).allSatisfy(date -> assertThat(date).isAfter(dateThree));
```

hope it helps and is a cool enough syntax for you ;-)

Comment: This is very cool ;-) Much better than what I did in terms of readability. And I figured out that I was using old version of AssertJ package.
Thanks.